# process is not defined on Next Page that use a HOC only on first render

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, higher-order-components

I am trying to use a [Higher-Order Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) to read some values from the server (As environment configuration) in NextJS and React. The versions are `12.0.3` and `17.0.2` respectively. Also I am using Typescript.

I am tryng to use a HOC in order to reuse this functionality. When I was using a `getServerSideProps` method everything was fine, but now the first render when I start the app is failing. It is important to mention that everytime I just refresh the page, all seems to work correctly

This is my HOC:

```
// src/components/app/withEnvironment.tsx
import {
  EnvironmentValues,
  readPublicEnvironmentValues,
} from 'config/environment';
import {NextPage} from 'next';
import {EnvironmentProvider} from 'providers';

export function withEnvironment<TProps>(
  Page: NextPage,
): (props: TProps & {environmentValues: EnvironmentValues}) => JSX.Element {
  const PageWithEnvironment = ({
    environmentValues,
    ...props
  }: TProps & {environmentValues: EnvironmentValues}) => {
    return (
      <EnvironmentProvider value={environmentValues}>
        <Page {...props} />
      </EnvironmentProvider>
    );
  };

  (PageWithEnvironment as NextPage).getInitialProps = () => {
    return {
      environmentValues: readPublicEnvironmentValues(),
    };
  };

  return PageWithEnvironment;
}
```

And this is how I am trying to implement it:

```
// src/pages/change-sets/index.tsx
import {withEnvironment} from 'components/app';
import {useEnvironment} from 'providers'

function ChangeSetPage(): JSX.Element {

  const environmentValues = useEnvironment();

  return (
    <div>
        <h1>ChangeSetPage</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withEnvironment(ChangeSetPage);
```

`EnvironmentProvider` and `useEnvironment` are part of a context that I would like to use to use to share values. This is how I defined them:

```
import {EnvironmentValues} from 'config/environment';
import React, {useContext} from 'react';

const EnvironmentContext = React.createContext<EnvironmentValues>(
  {} as EnvironmentValues,
);

export const EnvironmentProvider = EnvironmentContext.Provider;
export const EnvironmentConsumer = EnvironmentContext.Consumer;
export function useEnvironment(): EnvironmentValues {
  return useContext(EnvironmentContext);
}
```

Finally, the method `readPublicEnvironmentValues` only try to extract ENV values from the server, but as I mentioned on the first load process variable is always undefined;

```
export function readPublicEnvironmentValues(): EnvironmentValues {

  // Here is where the exception throws becaouse of there is no process variable only at first attempt
  const typedOptions = process.env as EnvironmentOptions;

  const currentEnv = ENVIRONMENTS.find(
    e => e === typedOptions.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV || e === typedOptions.APP_ENV,
  );

  if (currentEnv) {
    const values: EnvironmentValues = {
      currentEnv,
      skipAuth:
        typedOptions.DEBUG === 'true' &&
        typedOptions.SKIP_AUTH_ON_DEBUG === 'true',
    };

    if (typedOptions.BACKEND_PIVOT)
      values.backendPivotApi = typedOptions.BACKEND_PIVOT;

    if (typedOptions.BACKOFFICE_PIVOT)
      values.backofficePivotApi = typedOptions.BACKOFFICE_PIVOT;

    return values;
  } else {
    throw 'It is necessary to define an environment for the application. Please set NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV or APP_ENV';
  }
}
```

It seems the getInitialProps method is being executed on the client side. This is the error message:

[image: Error]

Comment: Can you show us the exact error you're getting?

Comment: It seems the getInitialProps method is being executed on client side. I just edited the description with the image

Comment: Does it work if you replace all `typedOptions` references, and use `process.env` directly to access the environment variables?

Comment: No, it does't work.